# How do I highlight 1 image at a time in an image gallery using react or css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm creating an image selection modal, and want the user to only choose 1 image. I know how to get that unique image and push that data, but I don't know how to highlight one individual image at a time.

For example, if the user clicks on 1 image that image should have a blue border around it, but if they click on another image, then the 2nd image will have a blue border and the other image will lose that border.

There could potentially be hundreds of images, so I can't write it out by hand. How can I do this?

Here's some of my code, pretty basic stuff.

```
imageChosen = (e) => {
  console.log(e)
};

<div className={classes.imageList}>
  <div className={classes.imageWrap}>
     <img onClick={(e) => this.imageChosen(e.target.src)} src="smallfamilyadv.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div className={classes.imageWrap}>
     <img onClick={(e) => this.imageChosen(e.target.src)} src="BugzPlaypark.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div className={classes.imageWrap}>
     <img onClick={(e) => this.imageChosen(e.target.src)} src="play-park-500x500.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you just add a class like "active" when the image is clicked. and remove all other active classes on the other images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a state, and an array list

```
state = {
 imageChosen : undefined;
}

render() {
 const img = ["smallfamilyadv.jpg","BugzPlaypark.jpg", "play-park-500x500.jpg"]

 return <div className={classes.imageList}>
  {img.map((e,i)=> {
   return <div key={i} className={this.state.imageChosen === e ? classes.imageWrapSelected : classes.imageWrapNormal}>
      <img onClick={(e) => this.setState({imageChosen:e.target.src})} src={e} alt={e} />
   </div>
  })} 
 </div>
}
```